# Spring jar can't see resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jar, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I have Spring Boot web app which work on IntelliJ. I build jar file from maven. Jar starts but css, js and img "blocked" in Chrome console show error 404, Firefox show Error 403. I unpack jar to check resouces folders and they OK. How solve the problem?

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't get those files with you in that package. How did you create the .jar file?

1. I rightclick on my pom.xml file, then choose "Run as -> Mavenbuild..."
2. I write "package" (as "Goals:" value, but the cursor just goes there for me automatically).
3. Click run.
4. It should now compile a complete .jar file in the "target" direcetory of your app.

Sometimes this will fail the first time i try to build my package (for some reason unknown to me) and then succeed the second time so before you give up, try it 2-3 times.

Comment: I create in console bu this command: mvn package spring-boot:repackage

Comment: Have you tried my way? I'm not very familiar with doing it your way, but my way works for me.